# horizontal scroll for table not working in react js

Tags: css, reactjs, html-table

Thanks for the help in advance. I am developing the HTML of a website using react. In it, I used a simple table. I need to implement an x scroll for the table on mobile devices. But the scroll is not working.What I have tried

```
<div className="cart-body">
      <table className="cart-table w-100">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colSpan={2}>Item</th>
            <th className="price">Price</th>
            <th className="qty">Qty</th>
            <th className="subTotal">Subtotal</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr className="cart-item-info">
            <td>
              <a
                href="#!"
                title="French Pastel Herringbone Tweed"
                className="product-item-photo d-block"
              >
                <img src="/images/img_5562.png" alt="proimage-1" />
              </a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a href="#!" className="item__name">
                French Pastel Herringbone Tweed
              </a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span className="price">$27.00</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div className="qty">
                <input type="text" defaultValue="3" />
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span className="subtotal">$81.00</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td className="p-0">
              <div className="tblIcons">
                <a href="#!">
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPenToSquare} />
                </a>
                <a href="#!">
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} />
                </a>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colSpan={5}>
              <div className="Subtotal">
                Subtotal: <span>$81.00</span>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.cart-body {
        overflow-x: auto;
        width: 600px;
}
```

Can anyone help me to sort out the issue.Screenshot of the issue
[image]

Comment: You would want a responsive design so it would fit for 400px screens. And you can solve it for example with `media query`

Comment: Thanks for the help. The scroll diddn't worked because I used display:flex for the container wrap

Comment: Still my friend, I would suggest thinking about smaller screens, it would better user experience and nicer design + if you don't know how to do it, you will learn smth new, that is always good :)

Comment: Sure will do as you suggested..Thanks for your support and valuable advice